# How to export Scala Spark project to jar

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, sbt

Im working on Scala/Spark project,i would like to export my project to jar file and run it into spark via spark-submit.
I tried this solution : 
File -> Project Structure -> Artifacts -> + -> Jar -> From modules with dependencies -> Selected Main Class after browsing -> selected extract to the target jar -> Directory for META-INF automatically gets populated -> OK -> Apply -> OK -> Build -> Build Artifacts -> Build.
But i didn't find my main class on the jar file so i can't run it.

Answer (score 4):

**The basic Idea that you can follow:**

As you are working on Scala

- You can use `sbt` as your build management system to add all the dependencies to your project
- You can use `sbt assembly` pluggin to build fat jar
- Export this fat jar into your cluster to submit the spark jobs.

pls use Google to get more details...

or you can use this project https://github.com/khodeprasad/spark-scala-examples to start with and integrate `sbt assembly` plugin to create fat jars by following their documentation https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly

Comment: I used sbt compile,but i got error "not found : value Trigger .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("200 seconds") ,knowing that i imported : import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.Trigger

Comment: have you added corresponding dependencies in your sbt file??

Comment: Yes i added,th error appeared only when i run sbt compile but when i compile the file there is no error

Comment: @AhmedRadhwenKhadhri create a new question, showing your sbt configuration and the code snippets where you are using Trigger class and share the link here